# Interrupt is not running after resume thread in STM32F103C8

Tags: multithreading, stm32, interrupt-handling, freertos, faultexception

I have three Threads Running in y code in main function I am declaring 3 Threads and suspend Two of them. My Interrupt Routine calls a function which after words resumes the one Task named "Swing". But While this task is running whenever interrupt occurs it does not run at all. And Other task is not running during this time.

```
{
    osThreadDef(defaultTask, StartDefaultTask, osPriorityNormal, 0, 128);
    defaultTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(defaultTask), NULL);
    osThreadDef(SwingTask, Swing, osPriorityNormal, 0, 128);
    SwingTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(SwingTask), NULL);
    osThreadDef(Task1, Task1, osPriorityNormal, 0, 100);
    osThreadCreate(osThread(Task1), NULL);
    vTaskSuspend(defaultTaskHandle);
    vTaskSuspend(SwingTaskHandle);
    vTaskStartScheduler();
}
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal example of your problem code here? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: {                                                                               
  osThreadDef(defaultTask, StartDefaultTask, osPriorityNormal, 0, 128);
  defaultTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(defaultTask), NULL);
 osThreadDef(SwingTask, Swing, osPriorityNormal, 0, 128);
 SwingTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(SwingTask), NULL);
 osThreadDef(Task1, Task1, osPriorityNormal, 0, 100);
 osThreadCreate(osThread(Task1), NULL);
 vTaskSuspend(defaultTaskHandle);
 vTaskSuspend(SwingTaskHandle);
 vTaskStartScheduler(); }  <-- Main Code

Comment: And the function which is called by interrupt routine is

Comment: I think that's not enough. How do you configure your Interrupt Routine? what does your Interrupt Routine? and what does SwingTask?.
Please add this info to your main post, inside a code section.